# Devise 3.0.0rc custom attributes and strong parameters in Rails 4

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters, uninitialized-constant

I used [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters) solution based on `devise_parameter_sanitizer` to set some custom attributes to my [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) (User) model and make them available at sign_up and edit forms.

Everything works fine but from time to time (and it happens pretty often) specifically when I sign in, sign out or edit user (so I assume the problem is related to sessions), I get the following error:

[image: Devise Parameter Sanitizer]

Is there any logic that I can add to my code above to present this issue?

Comment: so did you add `User::ParameterSanitizer` class to your app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this was a little while ago but wanted to put an answer here because this actually took me a bit to solve and other people might have a similar issue.

Because you used an initializer to load the User:ParameterSanitizer when you change the application controller or anything that would cause it to reload (because you are in debug mode) the initialization is lost.

This is easy to test to confirm this is what was happening to you:
First: start the server fresh and go to your login page: should work.
Next: modify application_controller.rb (just put a space somewhere and hit save)
Next: visit your login page again (not working anymore) :(

Comment: Yes, you're right. So this just happens in debug mode or do I have to worry about production?

Comment: It would only happen in Debug because in production it doesn't reload code on the fly.